# Django Middleware plugins vs. Views

Tags: python, django, django-views, middleware, django-middleware

I am learning Django and came upon the concept of middleware. I having a hard time understanding the difference between middleware and logic contained in a view.

My understanding is that middleware is python logic that grabs data from sources outside of a websites main db, whereas a view is python logic to grab from the main website db?

Is this understanding correct? If not, can somebody help explain? If it is correct, is a middleware just an API call then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No not at all. Where did you get that idea? Middleware is for shared code that runs on all requests, before or after the view.

The docs have a full explanation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: Hmm..I read that page but I guess I'm not understanding how this shared middleware code is any different from the code in the django view, since all the business is theoretically suppose to lie here. Can't the middleware code just reside in the view?

Comment: But it's code that is run for *all* views. For example, the built-in middleware does things like make the logged-in user available via `request.user`. You wouldn't want to do that individually for every view.